# AttributeError: module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'run_tesseract'

Tags: python, anaconda, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use the run_tesseract function to get an hocr output for extracting text from an image for Bank receipt images.However I am getting the above error message. I have installed Tesseract-OCR on my laptop, and have also added its path to my System Path variable.I have a windows 10 64 bit operating system,

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it also but to no avail.

```py
import glob
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img_files=glob.glob('./NACH/*.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract OCR\\tesseract.exe'
#im=Image.open(img_files[0])
#im.load()

pytesseract.run_tesseract(img_files[0],'output',lang='eng',config='hocr')
```

I get the following complete Error Message:

> AttributeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in
>
> 4 im=Image.open(img_files[0])
>
> 5 im.load()
>
> ----> 6 pytesseract.run_tesseract(img_files[0],'output',lang='eng',config='hocr')
>
> 7 #text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
>
> 8 #if  os.path.isfile('output.html'):AttributeError: module
>   'pytesseract' has no attribute 'run_tesseract'

Comment: Replace pytesseract.run_tesseract() with  pytesseract.pytesseract.run_tesseract()

Comment: You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Nithin It gives an error:
TypeError: run_tesseract() missing 1 required positional argument: 'extension'

Comment: Ok.I added .jpg as a value in the extension parameter since that is the input image type.I hope I am correct.

Comment: Thank you Nithin.Can you explain why pytesseract needs to be used twice in  pytesseract.pytesseract.run_tesseract()?

Comment: That's because `pytesseract` is also the name of the module inside the pytesseract package. Changing the original `import pytesseract` to `from pytesseract import pytesseract` makes the original command run properly. (I commented also below the original accepted answer so that future readers don't miss it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `pytesseract.run_tesseract()` with `pytesseract.pytesseract.run_tesseract()`.

*Credit Nithin in the comments. Adding this as an answer to close it out.*

Comment: Or replace `import pytesseract` with `from pytesseract import pytesseract` and the original command will run properly.